# visionos sim and CloudKit. how to select production environment

Tags: cloudkit

Has anyone managed to get the visionos simulator to use the production CloudKit container environment? I have an app in development for visionOS which is already running on Mac OS. In the Mac version, using an entitlements entry I can switch from development to production cloud containers as needed. However, the same entitlement entry in visionOS has no effect and CloudKit can only access the development containers.